# Some Object changing scale in Rendered mode

Tags: rendering, error

[image]
[image]

I'm studing Blender with Blenderguru youtube.
this is the donut in blenderguru tutorial.

in RenderMode, Donut scale is changed.
(rendering is same)
but in other mode, everything is good.

I don't understand this problem, so I ask here.
I'm sorry about my poor English.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trkvfdoX8v_d_AIlseS5FiR18F6aAFTX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check your "Midlevel" value on "Displacement" node in Donut material. You have "20.70". It is too high and this is the reason of your problem. Please change value to "0.0" or "0.5" and everything will be fine ;)

Comment: Oh! Fixed it! Thank you for your help!